# I need to merge betwwen UITexView text to UIImageView to one UIImage

Tags: objective-c

I need to merge UITextView and UIImageView to one UIImage.

I try to convert UITextView (background color is clear) to UIImage but the background turn to black after this code.

```
#define IS_OS_7_OR_LATER    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)

-(UIImage*)imageFromView:(UIView*)view
{

CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
UIImage *image;

if (IS_OS_7_OR_LATER)
{
    //Optimized/fast method for rendering a UIView as image on iOS 7 and later versions.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, scale);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
else
{
    //For devices running on earlier iOS versions.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size,YES, scale);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

return image;
}
```

Comment: FYI - 1) Are you really supporting iOS 6? 2) You should avoid macros like `IS_OS_7_OR_LATER`. Learn how to properly check for the existence of supported APIs. Read the [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i).

Comment: @rmaddy Not related to question, but check "available" macro for Swift2. Apple changed way you should check for new APIs, as a method or class can be available, but privately... so that macro is indeed safer way to do this.

Comment: @DarthMike But the question is about Objective-C, not Swift. And no, that macro is not safer than the proper way.

Comment: @rmaddy I meant pitfalls mentioned, for example in this post: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/checking-api-availability-with-swift.html. Even though 'available' is Swift-only, user-defined macros can be used in ObjC. Why checking for OS version would be less safe? (Sorry Roei for unrelated discussion).

Comment: @DarthMike It's better to check the method is available for that class as opposed to checking float version numbers as let's say Apple decides to change the way they name each OS for future releases. Instead of using numbers they change to names, like OSX or Android do? Then this way of checking by version float numbers could be potentially unstable.

Comment: @JimTierney I understand the way that macro is implemented, is not safe. There's other ways to check OS version, like NSProcessInfo on iOS8. With that in mind, I still think checking for OS version is the safest way to switch API use. Apple has taken that route with Swift, which shows acknowledge the problem. We need to move on and review our practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(UIImage*)imageFromView:(UIView*)view
{
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    UIImage *image;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, scale);

    if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)]) {
        [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    }else{
        [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    }

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

If you can change your method to the code above

**(please note the correct way to change method according to OS - if class responds to that method check)** -

The `opaque` boolean should be `NO`, where your code was asking the view to be opaque. Changing it to say `NO` should make it clear and solve your issue. I haven't had chance to test this code, though it should work. If not then at the very least the OS checking is better this way.

I hope this help

Thanks